# Как ввести два числа через пробел в Python?

Tags: python

Как написать код, где надо ввести два числа через пробел в Python
Например:
Нам надо написать программу, которая читает два числа через пробел, а потом складывает их
P.S.

```
a, b = int (input(), input()) # не работает
```

Comment: `a, b = эй, слыш, два числа мне` тоже не работает

Comment: В докуминтации Python смотрел этот способ, но он не правильно работает, пишет что только если скачать плагин Дворовой лексикон

Comment: Для python эти две записи одинаково непонятны, разница лишь в том, что ваша формально проходит синтаксическую проверку

Answer (score 2):

Ввод двух (или более) переменных через пробел:

```py
a,b=map(int,input().split())
```

Answer (score -1):

Если требуется сделать ее проще, без `split()` или `' '.join()`.
То можно просить 2 переменные int и выводить их отдельной строкой

Ок, увидел что нужно.

```
print(' '.join(x for x in input().split()))
```

Comment: 2 4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Админ/Desktop/Python/python1.py", line 1, in <module>
    a, b = int(input()), int(input())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2 4' Выводится вот эта ошибка

Comment: Задача не выводить отдельной строкой, а вводить.